# 'Teams' Control bar is not activated when my WinForms application is being displayed

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, wndproc

i have a Winforms application that does trap some events in WndProc handler, in order to be able to resize and move the window.

What i noticed was, when the application is active in the sharing window of Teams, the top control bar will not appear

[Teams Control bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNVX4.jpg)

What i am wondering, is what event am i trapping or how can i enable the control bar to appear, this doesn't happen when other applications are active, the control bar appears just fine, only when my application has focus, so i am sure its some event that i am preventing from leaving the appl.

the specific event that i am trapping, is WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;

```
       protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
       {
          if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
           {  
               Point pos = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
               pos = this.PointToClient(pos);
               //if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
               {
                   // move by title bar
                   if (pos.X > cGrip && pos.X <= (this.ClientSize.Width - cGrip) && pos.Y > cBorderWidth && pos.Y < cCaption)
                   {
                       m.Result = (IntPtr)HTCAPTION; // move
                       return;
                   }
                   // resize top/right corner
                   if (pos.X >= this.ClientSize.Width - cGrip && pos.Y <= cGrip)
                   {
                       m.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOPRIGHT;
                       return;
                   }
                   //resize top left corner
                   if (pos.X <= cGrip && pos.Y <= cGrip)
                   {
                       m.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOPLEFT;
                       return;
                   }
                   //resize top
                   if (pos.X > cGrip && pos.Y <= cBorderWidth && pos.Y > 0 && pos.X < (this.ClientSize.Width - cGrip))
                   {
                       m.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOP;
                       return;
                   }

                   // resize bottom Right
                   if (pos.X >= this.ClientSize.Width - cGrip && pos.Y >= this.ClientSize.Height - cGrip)
                   {
                       m.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
                       return;
                   }
                   // resize right side
                   if (pos.X >= this.ClientSize.Width - cBorderWidth && pos.Y >= cGrip && pos.Y <= this.ClientSize.Height - cGrip)
                   {
                       m.Result = (IntPtr)HTRIGHT;
                       return;
                   }


                   // resize top left
                   if (pos.X <= cGrip && pos.Y > this.ClientSize.Height - cGrip)
                   {
                       m.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMLEFT;
                       return;
                   }

                   // resize left side
                   if (pos.X <= cBorderWidth && pos.Y >= cGrip && pos.Y <= this.ClientSize.Height - cGrip)
                   {
                       m.Result = (IntPtr)HTLEFT;
                       return;
                   }

                   //resize bottom
                   if (pos.Y >= (this.ClientSize.Height - cBorderWidth) && pos.X >= cGrip && pos.X < (this.ClientSize.Width - cGrip))
                   {
                       m.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOM;
                       return;
                   }

                   m.Result = (IntPtr)HTNOWHERE;
                   return;
               }
           }
           
               base.WndProc(ref m);
       }
```

i have tried removing the return following the m-Result, that doesn't work and actually prevents me from being able to resize or move the application window.